# can octopress markdown read reference link from other file?

Tags: hyperlink, markdown, octopress

I building my first Octopress blog in windows platform, and found duplicate reference link in each post.

```
# new_post.markdown
[google]
[google]: http://google.com
```

Can i collect all reference link in one file name reflink.markdown and include it for reuse?

```
# reflink.markdown
[google]: http://www.google.com
[yahoo]: http://www.yahoo.com
[xxx]: http://xxx.com
```

Then i tried add the follow line to new_post.markdown and it is work!!!

```
{% include reflink.markdown %}
```

But I want to escape this step in each post, any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Add below line

> {% include reflink.markdown %}

in `post.html` inside the `_layout` folder.